# How to pass error message to mvc view in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using ajax to call controller action method on mvc button click event. Controller action method  has validation logic which if failed user should be notified an error. I'm not sure how i can achieve this in MVC . Is there a way I can send error message to the ajax success event from controller?.

```
 Controller Action Method
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ViewResult Index(ProfileSnapshotRequestModel pspm)
    {

        // Do something 
       return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

MVC view button click

```
   $("#copyData").click(function() {

            var selectedRowId = $('#ServersWS').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
            var rowData = jQuery("#ServersWS").jqGrid('getRowData', selectedRowId);
            $("#MainDiv").prop('disabled', true);
            var url = '@Url.Action("Index")';
            HideElements();
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                            BaseEnvtId: $("#SelectedEnvironmentID").val(),
                            BaseVersionId: $("#SelectedVersionID").val(),
                            BaseProfileId: rowData['ProfileId'],
                            NewEnvtId: $("#SelectedEnvironmentID2").val(),
                            NewVersionId: $("#SelectedVersionID2").val(),
                            NewProfileId: $("#SelectedProfileID2").val(),
                },
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById('displaySuccess').style.display = 'block';
                    $("#ProfileCopyDiv").prop('disabled', true);
                    $("#MainDiv").prop('disabled', false);
                },
                error: function() { alert('something bad happened'); }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I was able to resolve it by changing the controller action return type as Action Result and then do some thing like this  return Json(new { success = true });

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it by changing the controller action return type as **Action Result** and then use Json object to return data what i want to - For example

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Index(ProfileSnapshotRequestModel pspm)
    {
         // Do something 
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

Comment: Change the return type of the action method to JsonResult so that it's obvious for a caller what response to expect. In case of an error, a sample result could be: return Json(new { success = false, errors = new [] { "error1 description", "error2 description" } });